# Issue in matching java.util.Date using Hamcrest in Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, spring-restcontroller, hamcrest, java.util.date

I am writing a Test Case for a REST Controller. Code below:

```
 private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
     @Test
     public void getByExternalTransactionId() throws Exception {
            EquityFeeds equityFeeds = new EquityFeeds(423,"SAPEXTXN1", "GS", "ICICI", "BUY", dateFormat.parse("22/11/13"), 101.9f, "BLO", "Y",0);
            when(equityFeedsService.findByExternalTransactionId("SAPEXTXN1")).thenReturn(equityFeeds);
            mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/equityFeeds/getByExternalTransactionId/{externalTransactionId}", "SAPEXTXN1"))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", Matchers.hasSize(10)))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", Matchers.is(423)))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.externalTransactionId", Matchers.is("SAPEXTXN1")))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.clientId", Matchers.is("GS")))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.securityId", Matchers.is("ICICI")))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.transactionType", Matchers.is("BUY")))
    //                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.transactionDate", Matchers.is(dateFormat.parse("22/11/13"))))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.transactionDate", Matchers.is(Date.parse("22/11/13"))))       
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.marketValue", Matchers.is(101.9f)))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.sourceSystem", Matchers.is("BLO")))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.priorityFlag", Matchers.is("Y")))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.processingFee", Matchers.is(0)));
            verify(equityFeedsService, times(1)).findByExternalTransactionId("1");
            verifyNoInteractions(equityFeedsService);
        }
```

Issue:

It's breaking in transactionDate which is `java.util.Date` in POJO. I have tried below in the test case:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.transactionDate", Matchers.is(dateFormat.parse("22/11/13"))))
```

This gives me the output

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.transactionDate"
Expected: is <Fri Nov 22 00:00:00 IST 2013>
     but: was <1385058600000L>
Expected :is <Fri Nov 22 00:00:00 IST 2013>
Actual   :<1385058600000L>
```

Then I tried:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.transactionDate", Matchers.is(Date.parse("22/11/13"))))
```

This gave me the output:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.transactionDate"
Expected: is <1412965800000L>
     but: was <1385058600000L>
Expected :is <1412965800000L>
Actual   :<1385058600000L>
```

This looks to be very close. I understand that the difference in value is because the time the date was created in POJO is milliseconds is different from the time the date was created in the `.andExpect(jsonPath("$.transactionDate", Matchers.is(Date.parse("22/11/13"))))` lines and hence the values are different, as also the values are long since the values are in milliseconds.

My TestCase is failing only because of this field. I am really out of my mind as to how should I solve this. I have to use java.util.Date. Any others solution for this?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: 1 412 965 800 000 close to 1 385 058 600 000? Well, the difference is “only” 27 907 200 000. ;-)

Comment: Is Fri Nov 22 00:00:00 IST 2013 correct and the actual value wrong? Or is 1385058600000L correct and the expected `Date` object wrong?

Comment: @Ole: I thought of using LocalDate but then I have other issues using LocalDate and hence I used java.util.Date. I have to make a lot of changes and solve other issue like de serializing JSON  date having LocalDate as one of its members. I would in lot of trouble. Do we have any solution which uses java.util.Date. ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: If I understand correctly (not familiar with Hamcrest), you need to feed an old-fashioned `java.util.Date` object into the `EquityFeeds` constructor and test that the  `long` value that you get back out — `1385058600000L` or 1 385 058 600 000 — agrees with the `Date` you specified.

### java.time

To construct the `java.util.Date` that you need:

```
    Instant transactionTime = LocalDate.of(2013, Month.NOVEMBER, 22)
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toInstant();
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(transactionTime);
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

Output so far when running in Asia/Kolkata time zone:

> Fri Nov 22 00:00:00 IST 2013

Now just pass `oldfashionedDate` as the 6th argument to the `EquityFeeds` constructor. The point in the above lines of code is not only that we’re using the java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and it is very clear to read from the code what it does; it also makes testing easy. To produce the expected `long` value:

```
    long expectedTransactionDateMillis = transactionTime.toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println(expectedTransactionDateMillis);
```

> 1385058600000

Not being familiar with Hamcrest and not having tried I would expect that you just need to fill this value into your assertion:

```
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.transactionDate", Matchers.is(expectedTransactionDateMillis)))
```

The `java.util.Date` class is poorly designed and long outdated. I recommend you don’t use it, and I even more strongly recommend you don’t use the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. Even though `Date` is used in your production code for historical reasons, I see no reason why you should repeat that mistake in your tests. Use java.time, it is so much nicer to work with. And conversions exist for when you need an object of one of the outdated types like `Date`.

### What went wrong in your test?

Your first attempt:

```
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.transactionDate", Matchers.is(dateFormat.parse("22/11/13"))))
```

The result of `dateFormat.parse("22/11/13")` is a `java.util.Date`. Even though this is equal to the `Date` in your POJO, the value in your JSON is a `long` representing a count of milliseconds since the epoch (a practice you may want to change if you can). Since a `Date` and a `long` can never be equal, your test fails.

You then tried:

```
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.transactionDate", Matchers.is(Date.parse("22/11/13"))))
```

Now you are getting a `long` value alright. We can see that the expected and actual values have the same format in the printed output. There are two things wrong:

1. You are using the `Date.parse` method that has been deprecated since 1997. It has been so because it works unreliably across time zones. Even if you insisted on using `Date`, you should still stay far away from those deprecated methods and constructors.
2. Your date string gets parsed into 1 412 965 800 000, equal to 2014-10-11T00:00+05:30, so it’s nearly a year off. That method is not only deprecated, it is also confusing and parses your date string as the 11th day of the 22nd month of 2013. There is no 22nd month of the year, but the `parse` method just extrapolates, keeps counting months into 2014 and ends up with October that year. One more reason not to use that method.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: It (java.util.Date) was getting very confusing for me. I have now used LocalDate in my application